# Autolayout broken in Xcode-9 beta

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, row-height, xcode9-beta

I am having `UITableView` in my one of screens. It shows section headers and rows with **dynamic height**.
There are two issues with this set-up when I moved from Xcode8.3 to Xcode-9 beta.

**1 Header view height broken

2 Dynamic height of rows broken**

I have set-up my table view as:

[image]
[image]

Then I have custom cell

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return //dynamically calculated height according to msg text
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 30
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerHeight:CGFloat = tableView.sectionHeaderHeight
    let headerView = HeaderView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.width, height: headerHeight), withHeaderLable: "Date/Day of msg")
    return headerView
}
```

This works perfect in Xcode8.3 even with multiple lines of msgs, but broken in Xcode9 beta as:
When I run with Swift3.2 settings in Xcode9 beta:

[image]

When I run with Swift4 settings in Xcode9 beta:

[image]

What would be the reason of this behavior?

Comment: Why are you using beta?

Comment: @elk_cloner that should be question, why using beta. It's an initiative to take a challenge with upcoming technologies. If this is really bug of Apple, then it would be helpful to us, to face such challenges and find out proper solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 30.0
```

Add this in your `viewDidLoad` and no need of tableview delegate method `estimatedHeightForRowAt`.

Comment: Still wonder why it needs this in xcode9 and not in xcode8.3!

Comment: Actually the issue with header is not related to auto-layout, it's related to `NSFetchedResultsController`; [here's question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44804683/5546312)